# How can I pass a NSMutableDictionary value to multiple controllers in my storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an Objective-C controller called `LinkedInLoginController` and inside it I have a function that contains an NSDictionary called newResult as shown below:

```
- (void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
[self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result)
    {
        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);

        NSMutableDictionary *newResult = [result mutableCopy]; //copies the NSDictionary 'result' to a NSMutableDictionary called 'newResult'

        [newResult setObject: [newResult objectForKey: @"id"] forKey: @"AppUserID"]; //copies the value assigned to key 'id', to 'AppUserID' so the database can recognize it
        [newResult removeObjectForKey: @"id"]; //removes 'id' key and value

        LinkedInLoginJSON *instance= [LinkedInLoginJSON new]; //calls LinkedInPost method from LinkedInLoginJSON controller
        [instance LinkedInPost:newResult];

    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }
];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHotTopics" sender: self]; //Sends user on to Trending page after they sign in with LinkedIn

}
```

I am trying to pass the key value for `AppUserID` to four different Swift ViewControllers. What is the best way to do this? Passing it over with a segueway? I tried calling it directly from NSDictionary using this guide but was unsuccessful: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps

Comment: Is the value guaranteed to exist when the view controllers are presented? Passing during a segue is one way. Are the four controllers going to be "nested", presented one after the other? Perhaps it's better to create a singleton class and give it an "appUserId" property that all the controllers can access without having to make properties and passing values. On one of my apps, there is what I would consider an "app-wide" property that all my controllers need to know. So I subclassed UIApplication and gave it the property I needed then imported the header into all my controller files.

Comment: @user2320861 That sounds like exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. How exactly can I do that since my `LinkedInLogInController` is in Objective-C but my ViewControllers in my storyboard are in Swift? Can you elaborate on how to create a singleton class and give it the `AppUserID`? Sorry, I'm relatively new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton, new file->cocoaclass subclass of nsobject
in .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShowTimer : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *passed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *passed;
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ShowTimer.h"

@implementation ShowTimer
@synthesize passed;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static ShowTimer *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}
@end
```

in your view controllers import `#import "ShowTimer.h"` then  set or get the object it.

set your object

```
ShowTimer *timer=[ShowTimer sharedManager];
timer.passed=newResult;
```

get your object

```
ShowTimer *timer=[ShowTimer sharedManager];
NSMutableDictionary *newResult =timer.passed;
```

Sorry about the naming, I just copy and pasted another class to answer your question but you can change the naming if you want....

EDIT:
When you add an objective-c class to swift it will as you to bridging options then if you say yes it will add `-Bridging-Header.h`  to your project in that header just call `#import "ShowTimer.h"`

[image]

in your swift view controller use the code like this

```
var companies:NSMutableDictionary = ["AAPL" : "Apple Inc", "GOOG" : "Google Inc", "AMZN" : "Amazon.com, Inc", "FB" : "Facebook Inc"]
        var instance:ShowTimer = ShowTimer.sharedManager() as ShowTimer
        instance.passed=companies
        var dict:NSMutableDictionary=instance.passed
        NSLog("%@", dict);
```

I have never written swift code before but just research lit bit if my approach doesnt work for you

Comment: Thanks so much. It appears as though you are getting the object using Objective-C at the end of your answer. How would I get my object using Swift? Do I need to add `#import "ShowTimer.h"`? And what does the syntax look like for calling it from a Swift ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Obj-C and Swift are co-compatible at the moment (from what I understand).

In Obj-C I would create a new subclass of NSObject, maybe MySharedValues, so the header would look like this:

```
@interface MySharedValues : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) id appUserId;
+(instancetype)defaultInstance;
@end
```

And the implementation would look like:

```
@implementation
+(instancetype)defaultInstance{
    static MySharedValues *obj = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        obj = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return obj; 
}
@end
```

Then you can import `#import "MySharedValues.h"` into the headers of all your controllers. To access or set the value, you would call

```
[MySharedValues defaultInstance].appUserId;
```